# WSOD while sending headers, probably Cache-related

Tags: caching, wsod, http-request

I have a very strange problem with a fresh Drupal install: On some pages, I receive a WSOD with `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`:

[image: WSOD]

It happens for instance when on `admin/config/development/performance` I click *Clear all caches*. (But also other pages are affected – for instance the Layout Builder page of a Node type.)

Interestingly, I could isolate the bug down here: If in `vendor/symfony/http-foundation/Response.php::sendHeaders()` I tweak the code so that it unsets a lot of the headers to be sent (actually, all of them but `X-Generator` and `X-Frame-Options`), the error disappears.

```
...
$headers = $this->headers->allPreserveCaseWithoutCookies();
unset($headers['Cache-Control']);
unset($headers['Content-language']);
unset($headers['Date']);
unset($headers['X-Drupal-Dynamic-Cache']);
unset($headers['X-UA-Compatible']);
unset($headers['X-Content-Type-Options']);
unset($headers['Expires']);
unset($headers['Vary']);
foreach ($headers as $name => $values) {
  ...
```

Based on the headers I unset, it seems that it is a caching-related problem. (However, Caching is switched off, *Browser and proxy cache maximum age* is set to `<no caching>`.)

My setup:

- installed Drupal 8.7.5 via [composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/using-composer/using-composer-to-install-drupal-and-manage-dependencies#using-drupal-composerdrupal-project)
- on my local machine, a MacBook Pro with macOS High Sierra
- installed via Homebrew

  - PHP 7.3
  - Apache 2.4
  - MySQL 5.7.24

Any idea what the problem might be?

**Edit:** Regarding Apache error logs: I first had no entries there but now I debugged again and saw such one:

```
[core:notice] [pid 92592] AH00052: child pid 98466 exit signal Bus error (10)
```

Googling gave the [suggestion](https://processwire.com/talk/topic/4133-child-pid-exit-signal-bus-error-10/?do=findComment&comment=40570) to `apc_clear_cache();` but it's not available in PHP7. So I ran [opcache-reset()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.opcache-reset.php).

Result: Problem is still there, now already when opening the page `admin/config/development/performance`.

Now the error logs say:

```
 [core:notice] [pid 7428] AH00052: child pid 7446 exit signal Segmentation fault
```

Google [suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7745652/52023) this is likely  caused by a syntax error in `php.ini` or some included extension there. Thus I have taken out all extensions, including

```
zend_extension=/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20180731/opcache.so
```

but the problem remains.

**Edit 2:** Here's the output of my `php -i` (It uses the same `php.ini` file as `phpinfo()` in localhost). https://pastebin.com/ppvCpPA6

Comment: This might be easier to debug if you find the error log of the Apache instance you've installed via Homebrew and post the error message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I first had no error_log entries, now I debugged again and got some – find them in my Edit above.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have OPcache disabled completely when developing locally?

Comment: Thanks, just disabled it with `opcache.enable=0` in `php.ini`, problem remains.

Comment: Here's the output of my `php -i` (It uses the same `php.ini` file as `phpinfo()` in localhost). https://pastebin.com/ppvCpPA6

Comment: Be sure that your `/usr/local/etc/php/7.3/conf.d/ext-opcache.ini` doesn't override your `php.ini`, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/27640772/2199525.

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, it only contains this commented out line: `;zend_extension=/usr/local/opt/php/lib/php/20180731/opcache.so`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I could solve it myself. My Apache error logs did show

```
AH00052: child pid 7363 exit signal Segmentation fault (11)
```

so it must have been a problem with the Apache config.

I took the opportunity to **reinstall Apache and configure it with FCGI/FPM** [according to this](https://medium.com/@fahimhossain_16989/configuring-apache-with-php7-fpm-for-mac-os-x-using-homebrew-54a26bbdac7c) and now the problem is gone.

Comment: Hurray!!!!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

I have same issue with set debug mode when run

```
drupal smo dev
```

Problem will gone If I set to prod mode

```
 drupal smo prod
```

After sometime debug I found problem because cache tag header. And I change

```
http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: true
```

to

```
http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: false
```

It's working again.

Comment: Didn't know what [`smo`](https://hechoendrupal.gitbooks.io/drupal-console/en/commands/site-mode.html) meant. Where exactly did you change these tags?

Comment: @Jonh: Thanks, `drupal smo prod` gave me `PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Drupal\Component\DependencyInjection\Container::set($id, $service) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface::set($id, $service, $scope = self::SCOPE_CONTAINER) in /Users/jorge/data/my/code/test/d8/web/core/lib/Drupal/Component/DependencyInjection/Container.php on line 49`

Comment: @leymannx Grepping gave me `core/core.services.yml` – but my value is already `false` there.

Comment: @GeorgJähnig, the initial value in core.service.yml can be overwritten in /sites/default/services.yml or /sites/development.services.yml, the 2nd one only when enabled in settings.php, which is usually the case for dev modes, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/251768/error-500-premature-end-of-script-headers-index-php/283535#283535

Comment: @4k4 OK, thanks! I have no `sites/default/services.yml` file (nor `development.services.yml`), and even the `default.services.yml` (which I guess has no effect) has only a `http.response.debug_cacheability_headers: false` line.

Comment: @GeorgJähnig, OK, then you don't have an issue with too many tags in `X-Drupal-Cache-Tags`, which probably you had found already while debugging sendHeaders().